# Split String in Java based on open braces

Tags: java, string

```
Existing string:

stringToBeCleaned = author(A, UniqueVar1), author(B, UniqueVar1);

Expected String:

stringAfterCleaned = author(A, UniqueVar1)^author(B, UniqueVar1);
```

The method I wanted to try was split the string and join it appending the exponential symbol. But I have problems in splitting.

```
split = stringToBeCleaned.split(", ");
```

This does not give the required split.

```
split = stringToBeCleaned.split("), ");
```

This split throws error for the invalid regex, because the braces are not closed Is there any way to achieve this. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: braces are used for grouping and extracting strings in a regex, try escaping it like: \\(

Comment: Why bother splitting when you can just do: `stringToBeCleaned.replaceAll("\\), ","\\)^");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to escape the parenthesis:

```
split = stringToBeCleaned.split("\\), ");
```

Or you can just replace the comma without regex:

```
stringToBeCleaned = stringToBeCleaned.replace("), ", ")^");
```